# javascript regex to prepend string to variable names jupyter

Tags: javascript, regex, jupyter-notebook

I am migrating a Python code from a Jupyter notebook to a module.
The code presents many variables named like `name_arr` (eg. `time_arr`).
I would like to modify all of them prepending `TC.`, where TC is the instance
of a class I am progressively building on the side in the python module.

I have a rough idea of how to achieve this on `vim` (using `sed`, loops and ifs)
but I'd like to learn how to do it from within Jupyter using Javascript regex.

I've seen many answers on how to do it in a Javascript environment (I don't know Java).
What I don't get is how to do it in Jupyter Find & Replace tool.

Following a JS regex tutorial, I have tried `_arr$`
[image]
but this clearly does not capture all occurrences of the suffix.

Can somebody provide some insight/suggestion on how to do this?
Doing it by hand feels like a silly task, prone to mistakes.
Thank you

Comment: If that is JS flavor, use `\w+_arr\b` and replace with `TC.$&`

Comment: Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew if you put it into an answer I'll accept it and up vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
\w+_arr\b
```

and replace with

TC.$&

Details:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `_arr` - a substring
- `\b` - a word boundary.

`$&`  stands for the whole match value.